Prettier Plugins Not Found with Pre-Commit
I'm using Prettier with pre-commit to format my code before committing. However, I encountered an issue where Prettier doesn't seem to recognize the plugins.
With this setup, Prettier is not able to locate the plugins. I suspect this is because Prettier does not recognize the NODE_PATH environment variable.
- id: prettier
  name: prettier
  entry: prettier
  language: node
  args: ['--write', '--ignore-unknown']
  additional_dependencies:
    - prettier@3.3.2
    - prettier-plugin-gherkin@2.3.0
    - prettier-plugin-organize-imports

prettier.................................................................Failed
- hook id: prettier
- duration: 0.15s
- exit code: 1

[error] Cannot find package 'prettier-plugin-organize-imports' imported from /home/my-user/repositories/github.com/my-repo/my-project/noop.js

I managed to get it working by specifying the full paths to the plugins directly in the entry command, but I am unsure if this is the best practice.
Here is my .pre-commit-config.yaml configuration:
- id: prettier
  name: prettier
  entry: bash -c 'prettier --plugin $NODE_PATH/prettier-plugin-organize-imports/index.js --plugin $NODE_PATH/prettier-plugin-gherkin/dist/index.js "$@"' _
  verbose: true
  language: node
  pass_filenames: true
  args: ['--write', '--ignore-unknown']
  additional_dependencies:
    - prettier@3.3.2
    - prettier-plugin-gherkin@2.3.0
    - prettier-plugin-organize-imports

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a more elegant solution to ensure Prettier recognizes the plugins when using pre-commit?

I think we're running into this issue: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/15085.
Unfortunately, I was not able to solve the issue with changes in just our .pre-commit-config.yaml file.
You'll need to configure Prettier plugins using a dynamic resolve in a .prettierrc.js file. This file can live in your project root or a subdirectory.
.prettierrc.js:
// Allow Prettier in .pre-commit-config.yaml to find plugins.
// https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/15085
module.exports = {
  plugins:[
    require.resolve("prettier-plugin-gherkin")
  ],
};

and your .pre-commit-config.yaml:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: reformat_feature_files
        name: prettier
        language: node
        additional_dependencies:
          - prettier@3.3.3
          - prettier-plugin-gherkin@3.1.0
        entry: npx prettier --write --ignore-unknown --tab-width=4

or .pre-commit-config.yaml:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-prettier
    rev: v4.0.0-alpha.8
    hooks:
      - id: prettier
        name: prettier
        additional_dependencies:
          - prettier@3.3.3
          - prettier-plugin-gherkin@3.1.0
        args:
          - --tab-width=4

